# how to use jquery easing plugin to slide a layer based website

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to imitate the sliding effect of this website: http://www.mckinsey.com/

I went through the JS source but could not quite understand exactly how it is done.

I would like to get a working example running on jsbin.

This is what I've tried:

http://jsbin.com/useke4

Comment: Retagged from 'design' to 'web-design'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried jQuery plugin

http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-pageslide/

Comment: +1, very nice.  The modal demo here looks like it does almost exactly what the OP wants: http://derekperez.com/jquery-pageslide/demo/

Comment: this is not really the same effect. if you notice, in the website I showed, the left layer does not move, however, the layer on the right moves on TOP of the layer on the left.  This is not the case in the demo of this plugin.